# Is there a way to log all files that are created on a W2K8 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, monitoring, logging

I've got a W2K8 server with some IIS apps that are creating a lot of files. I would like to monitor what files are created and how big they are. Is there a tool I could use to log all files that are created on the system?

Answer (score 1):

1. I suggest running [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/ or something similar, as scheduled task. It enables to sort by date/size,etc.
2. You can make a filtered search query on windows explorer.
3. You can also consider adding log4net and embedding the feature in your apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the free version of DiskPulse disk change monitor, which is capable of monitoring all created, modified and deleted files.

The free version of DiskPulse can be downloaded here:

http://www.diskpulse.com